# Adding a target to a selector belonging to a different object

Tags: ios, swift2, selector, addtarget

I have a UIViewController like this:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  var webView: WKWebView?
  var backButton: UIButton?

  override func loadView() {
    self.webView = WKWebView()

    self.backButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    self.backButton?.addTarget(self.webView, action: #selector(goBack), for: .touchUpInside)
  }
}
```

This code attempts to connect the tapping of the back button to the `WKWebView`'s `goBack()` instance method. Notice that I've passed `self.webView` to the button's `addTarget()` call.

This results in a compilation error: `"Use of unresolved identifier 'goBack'"`. I thought the Swift compiler would be able to resolve `goBack()` to the `WKWebKit` instance.

The only way I can get this to compile is to pass in `self` and forward the `goBack()` call manually:

```
override func loadView() {
    self.webView = WKWebView()

    self.backButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    self.backButton?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(goBack), for: .touchUpInside)
  }
```

and

```
func goBack() {
  self.webView?.goBack()
}
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just qualify your selector:

```
#selector(self.webView.goBack)
```

Comment: Then should the first argument of addTarget() still be `self.webView`, or should it just be `self`?

Comment: @arlomedia It would be the `webView`. In message-passing terms, `self.webView` would be the *receiver* of the message identified by the selector  `#selector(self.webView.goBack)`. When that message is sent to `self.webView`, clicking your button would send it message `goBack`, which `self` doesn't respond to.